# %x usage in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I am very new to python, but I am trying some stuff.

```
print("%x"%(9))
```

gives output of 9

```
print("%x"%(10))
```

gives output of a

What is happening here? Why the difference?

Comment: `%x` prints the number in hexadecimal format. You should read about various number bases to understand this (binary/decimal/octadecimal/hexadecimal).

Comment: Because `9` is `9` in hexadecimal and `10` is `a`.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but: It is a good idea to always use a tuple as the right-hand operand of `%`, i.e. do `"%x" % (9,)`. Otherwise, you get nasty surprises when you actually try to display a tuple.

Comment: Kind of a side note, but important: I see you tagged with Python 3, so you should really move on to more *modern* formatting options, like [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Comment: @KlausD.can you post this answer on this thread, that is the answer that helped me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the number you are trying to enter is getting converted to Hexadecimal because you are using %x, if you want to  have 10 use %d in place of %x

```
print("%x"%(9))
output:9
print("%x"%(10))
output:a
print("%d"%(10))
output:10
```

Answer (score 1):

`%x` is the hexadecimal formatter in the [Python's format mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

If you want to have a decimal representation use `%d` instead:

```
print("%d" % 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use %x the numbers are getting converted to Hexadecimal, try using %d to get the same value without conversion.

Answer (score -1):

`%x or %X` are signed hexadecimal.

The alternate form causes a leading ‘0x’ or ‘0X’ (depending on whether the ‘x’ or ‘X’ format was used) to be inserted between left-hand padding and the formatting of the number if the leading character of the result is not already a zero.

more info at :
https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/formatting.html